# I want to create a pivot table but want to ignore cells that contain a specific word

Tags: excel

I have a table with a lot of dates and when there is no date, i manually typed ''N/A''. I want the pivot table that i will create to ignore the ''N/A'' because i will be making a chart out of it.

Any help ? Thank you guys

Comment: You can use a Slicer and have it "slice out" the "N/A" values. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about filtering out the #N/A.

One way is to drag that column into the top left box of the Field List and then filter out the #N/A that way. However you won't be able to have this column of data elsewhere in the pivot table.

Next, also in the field list you can right click and filter it out that way.

Lastly and the one I feel best suits your need: you can click the drop down on the "Column Labels" part of the pivot table and then filter from there by un-checking the "#N/A" part.

Additionally, when you say "manually" I hope you know you can highlight your whole data set and by clicking "Find & Select" in the Home tab of the ribbon, you can choose "Black Cells" and then type "#N/A" and hit `CTRL + Enter` to fill in all blanks with the #N/A

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: @Dorian I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: The op asked 6 question and got 6 answer but accepted 0

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, but I had a similar problem and maybe my input helps somebody. So, I wanted to group some values in the pivot table and create ranges, but the NA's were not allowing to do this. The solution was to leave all the **"NA"** cells **blank**, in this way excel recognizes that these blank spaces are NAs and not text or other data type that may impair your analysis from the pivot table.